# how to get context inside MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to do a splash screen for a React Native application.
I have succeeded but I have to add a custom font to the heading.

Below is my code for doing it, but clearly it is not working.

```
package com.hackerkid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import  android.content.Context;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "hackerkid";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView splashText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splashTitle);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/FredokaOne-Regular.ttf");
    splashText.setTypeface(face);
  }
}
```

`getAssests()` is not working, I am not able to get the current context to getAssests from it.
I am very new to android development.
I have tried `getApplicationContext()` but it did not work.

Kindly guide me how to get the context inside MainActivity.java

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactActivity class class provides you `getApplicationContext()`, so use this context inside MainActivity.java  class.

Check the following code snippet as per your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "hackerkid";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView splashText = findViewById(R.id.splashTitle);

    // This getApplicationContext() is from ReactActivity class.

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/FredokaOne-Regular.ttf");
    splashText.setTypeface(face);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error telling setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)  symbol not found.
@Usman Khan

Comment: Try to Clean & Rebuild the project again. Might be possible that it didn't get a proper reference